# 4:1 MUX using 3 2:1 inverting MUX

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

There is a way to implement 4:1 mux using 3 2:1 mux.
But after my derive, I do not see the equation like
$$ Y = AS_0S_1 + BS_0'S_1 + CS_0S_1' + DS_0'S_1' $$
(treat D<sub>0</sub> as A, D<sub>1</sub> as B...)
what is going on with my derivation?
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The next step is to expand "(...)(...)" to 9 subterms:

$$ Y = AS_0'CS_0' + AS_0'DS_0 + AS_0'S_1' + BS_0CS_0' + BS_0DS_0 + BS_0S_1' + S_1CS_0' + S_1DS_0 + S_1S_1' $$

Now sort it and remove redundancy:

$$ Y = ACS_0' + ADS_0S_0' + AS_0'S_1' + BCS_0S_0' + BDS_0 + BS_0S_1' + CS_0'S_1 + DS_0S_1 + S_1S_1' $$

Anything with \$ S_0S_0' \$ or \$ S_1S_1' \$ can never be true, so remove it:

$$ Y = ACS_0' + AS_0'S_1' + BDS_0 + BS_0S_1' + CS_0'S_1 + DS_0S_1 $$

Now, what about \$ ACS_0' \$ and \$ BDS_0 \$? Well, if both \$A\$ and \$C\$ are true, \$S_1\$ does not matter. The same is true for \$B\$ and \$D\$.